# PyQt4 Error: Make sure you have a working Qt qmake on your PATH

Tags: python, qt, qmake

I am attempting to get PyQt4 running on a windows 10 device with python 3.6.3. I have `sips` installed and built already in my python directory. However, when I run the `configure.py/configure-ng.py` file in the PyQt4 folder I get the following error: `Error: Make sure you have a working Qt qmake on your PATH.`

I'm not sure how to fix this problem or what `qmake` is. I apprectiate any answers on how to fix this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`qmake` is the name of Qt's build tool, which generates Makefiles or other files needed to compile code on any platform that Qt supports. To fix this, you need to find out where the `qmake` executable lives on your system.

If you know where the executable installed, just add that directory to your path. If you don't know, you'll have to find it somehow, by searching your computer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I used file explorer to search my computer and couldn't find anything called `qmake`... Is it possible I missed an installation or something?

Comment: @GreenSaber Have you installed Qt itself? `sip` is used to automatically generate bindings to Qt in Python, but you still need to have Qt installed somewhere.

Comment: lol that's probably it... where can I installed Qt? Can I use pip?

Comment: @GreenSaber No, Qt is not a Python package, so `pip` will not work. It's built entirely in C++ (which is why `sip` is needed to generate Python bindings). Look here (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-support.html) for details on how to download and install on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

For the case of Ubuntu:

`qmake` was installed but for some reason was not working with the default `python configure.py` command. So I checked for the available installation path using the command

```
$ whereis qmake
qmake: /usr/bin/qmake /usr/bin/X11/qmake /opt/anaconda2/bin/qmake
```

Then I supplied the first path with the `-q` option like so

```
$ python configure.py -q /usr/bin/qmake
```

You may also use `python3` instead of `python` if you prefer version 3.x. This worked well for me.