# how to set 'Qt’s qmake tool be on PATH'?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qmake

I am using raspbian(based on debian) and wanted to install pyqtwebengine but i am having some error on as-

```
pip install pyqtwebengine
```

[image: error]

its official website says-'pip will also build and install the bindings from the sdist package but Qt’s qmake tool must be on PATH, https://pypi.org/project/PyQtWebEngine/

. I had no qmake installed which i did but i dont know how to set it on path. this answer says to add to it by config.py file but i dont have config file( I am not sure which config file it meant - should i add one with configparser)-- [PyQt4 Error: Make sure you have a working Qt qmake on your PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46570466/pyqt4-error-make-sure-you-have-a-working-qt-qmake-on-your-path)

how do i resolve it?

Comment: It's unclear why you deleted the [previous](//stackoverflow.com/q/73543417/2001654) question which was practically identical (if you need to make changes, just use the [edit] button). Also, please take more care in *checking* the question before submitting, especially after copy/paste operations: read it again, check syntax, grammar and punctuation, and also consider reviewing the [checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648). Finally, it's always better to include logs as text, not as images, since they can have low quality and prevent proper reading, especially to visually impaired people.